# C++ switch falls through to default even when using break;

Tags: c++

This is an assignment for my high school programming class, and I didn't seem to do anything wrong. However, when I run the Windows debugger in VS express 2013, every case falls through to the default, even though I have `break;`s on all of them. I have no idea what I did wrong and I can't look it up at all.

```
// mauroc_switch.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char yesform;
cout << "Type ''yes,'' lowercased and romanized, in a non-English language." << endl;
cin >> yesform;

//***Here is the switch statement.***

switch (yesform){
case 'yes':
    cout << "This is the English ''yes.'' Please type a non-English version of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    break;
case 'ja':
    cout << "This is the German form of ''yes.'' It is also the Swedish and Norwegian form of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    break;
case 'si':
    cout << "This is both the Spanish and the Italian form of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    break;
case 'oui':
    cout << "This is the French form of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    break;
case 'hai':
    cout << "This is the Japanese form of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    break;
case 'da':
    cout << "This is the Russian form of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    break;
case 'ne':
case 'ye':
    cout << "This is a Korean form of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    break;
case 'naam':
case 'aiwa':
    cout << "This is an Arabic form of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    break;
case 'sim':
    cout << "This is the Portuguese form of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    break;
case 'haan':
    cout << "This is the Hindi form of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    break;
default:
    cout << "You either made a typo or you typed ''yes'' in an unsupported language. Please try again. ";
    break;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `case 'yes':` This line of code does not do what you think it does.  Also, a `char` holds a single character, not a set of characters.  You want `std::string` for that.

Comment: `yesform` is a single character, so it can't possibly hold a string. Further, even if you changed the declaration to something like `yesform   char[100]` your switch still wouldn't work because it would be comparing the address of `yesform` to the address of (for example) `haan`, which will always be unequal. Best of luck.

Comment: People are telling you that `'yes'` isn't what you think it is, but nobody has explained it. It's called a *multicharacter literal*. According to the C++ standard, it's "conditionally-supported, has type `int`, and has an implementation-defined value". C has the same "feature". It's very nearly useless.

Answer (score 7):

You are mixing characters and strings. Sadly, C++ allows a "character" like `'yes'`, but that is not really what you think it is. The other problem is that as soon as you switch to strings (`std::string`), you can not use `switch` anymore, but you need a sequence of `if-else` statements or some other way to match the strings.

Here's a simple example that should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string yesform;
    cout << "Type ''yes,'' lowercased and romanized, in a non-English language." << endl;
    cin >> yesform;

    if( yesform == "yes" )
        cout << "This is the English ''yes.'' Please type a non-English version of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    else if( yesform == "ja" )
        cout << "This is the German form of ''yes.'' It is also the Swedish and Norwegian form of ''yes.'' " << endl;
    else
        cout << "You either made a typo or you typed ''yes'' in an unsupported language. Please try again. ";

    return 0;
}
```

In your case, once you read the input into a string, try using a `std::map` to map the input to an output string. That will likely be sufficient for the above example and it'll make the code way more readable.

Comment: Please use proper indentation.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Tell this to OP. I usually try to adapt to OPs style if it is not too terrible. Although that is debatable in this case... OK, let me edit it... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use switch case for this assignment, then prior to your switch statement you will have to 'convert' your string into an integer value.  An example of this would be...

```
enum yesLanguage {YES, JA, OUI, ..., CI};

yesLanguage yesAnswer = YES;

if (yesform == 'yes'){
     yesAnswer = YES;
}

else if(yesform == 'ja'){
     yesAnswer = JA;
}
```

And so on, and then in your switch case you'd have

```
switch(yesLanguage)
   case YES:
      Your YES output here;
      break;
   case JA: 
      .........
```

And so on with the rest of your code as above in your original post.

However if you don't **need** to use a switch case, then just do the if/else method as stated by the post above me.

***EDITED to add enum.***
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: **At least** use an `enum class` for this, not meaningless integer values.

Comment: You aren't wrong, you could always declare a bunch of enums at the beginning of the document, but I was just being basic.  That's all, I know it's not the cleanest, but that's that.

Comment: But I did add the enum above.  Syntax may be a little off, but the idea is there.  I've not used c++ in probably a year, but I figured I could definitely help with this answer.